Incorrect similarity by Embeddings, How to fix it
I have one problem with texts similarities.
I have a query
"eight point two"

and when i make vector search, i get such results
sentences = [test]
model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')

embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
res = client.search(
    collection_name="test3",
    search_params=models.SearchParams(hnsw_ef=128, exact=False),
    query_vector=embeddings[0],
)
res


[ScoredPoint(score=0.74708945,'vector_data': 'eight point two'},
ScoredPoint(score=0.7437991,, 'vector_data': 'two point eight'}),  
ScoredPoint(score=0.70646083,  'vector_data': eight point two p1 '}, vector=None),

how to take into account word order?
i want to see
'eight point two'
'eight point two p1 '
'two point eight'


Something is wrong with your embedding / search code. The embedding similarity between 'eight point two' and 'eight point two' should be 1.0. In the example above, is test perhaps not 'eight point two'.
Regardless the embeddings should account for word order.
